# How do i switch between (or highlight) projects of the same solution in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, user-interface, visual-studio-2012

I am new to Visual Studio and this problem has been bugging me for days.

I have two projects in the same solution in Visual Studio 2012.

In my solution manager one of them is highlighted, so when I start it without debugging <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> the one highlighted starts.

How do I highlight (and then on pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> ) start the OTHER project? Without having the close and reopen the projects.

Comment: i believe you can right click on a project and set it as default project did you try that ?

Comment: @gamecat Always cool to have someone add a little style.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Right click -> Set as Startup Project.

Answer (score 11):

When you Right Click the Solution and check the properties you have the Startup project option, make that as **Current Selection**

So you can launch by toggling the selection.

Right now in your case it would be Single startup project which is why you are unable to launch them separately.

Comment: This seems easier to work with than constantly changing the startup project. This also works in visual studio 2013.

Answer (score 2):

Right click the project in the solution explorer and choose the option:

> Set as startup project